# Linked List Functions Trouble

Tags: c++, list

I am experiencing trouble trying to create a unit test for all the functions in my  Linked List. Mainly I'm having trouble with my insert function that builds but just does not insert, and my First function which just returns the data in the first slot of my Linked List.

I am getting the following error for my code: `newNodeCatch = myList.First();`

> Error C2440   'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'ListNode *'  UnitTest

PS. My teacher helped to create the Linked List with me so I assume it is all correct code but I find it quite difficult to follow.

**source.cpp**

```
void TestLinkedList()
{
    printf("\n====================================================\n");
    printf("       LINKED LIST FUNCTIONS TEST");
    printf("\n====================================================\n\n");

    LinkedList<int> myList;

    Iter<int> iter;

    printf("\nCreating and populating a new LinkedList . . .\n");

    myList.PushFront(6);
    myList.PushFront(3);
    myList.PushFront(1);

    myList.PushBack(78);
    myList.PushBack(12);
    myList.PushBack(34);

    printf("Testing operator overloads, peek at the code to see!\n");   

    cout << endl << "Current values are" << endl;

    iter = myList.Begin(); //=

    while (iter != myList.End()) // != ==
    {
        std::cout << iter.value() << std::endl; //value()
        ++iter; // --
    }

    ListNode<int>* newNode = new ListNode<int>;

    newNode->data = 5;

    myList.Insert(newNode);

    //moving the iter back to the start
    while (iter != myList.Begin()) // != ==
    {
        --iter; // --
    }

    cout << endl << "Current values are" << endl;
    while (iter != myList.End()) // != ==
    {
        std::cout << iter.value() << std::endl; //value()
        ++iter; //++ --
    }

    ListNode<int>* newNodeCatch = new ListNode<int>;

    newNodeCatch = myList.First();
}

int main()
{
    TestLinkedList();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

**LinkedList.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ListNode.h"
#include <crtdbg.h>

template <typename T>
class Iter
{
    ListNode<T>* current;

public:

    //=
    Iter& operator=(ListNode<T>* other)
    {
        //LinkedList<int> other1;
        current = other;
        return *this;
    }

    //!=
    bool operator!=(ListNode<T>* other)
    {
        if (current != other)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //==
    bool operator==(ListNode<T>* other)
    {
        if (current == other)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    //->
    T value()
    {
        return current->data;
    }

    //++
    void operator++()
    {
        current = current->next;
    }

    //--
    void operator--()
    {
        current = current->prev;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class LinkedList
{
public:

    LinkedList()
    {
        start = new ListNode<T>();
        _ASSERT(start);
        end = new ListNode<T>();
        _ASSERT(end);

        start->next = end;
        end->prev = start;

        start->prev = nullptr;
        end->next = nullptr;
    }

    ~LinkedList()
    {
        delete end;
        delete start;   
    }

    void PushFront(T data)
    {
        ListNode<T>* node = new ListNode<T>();
        _ASSERT(node);
        node->data = data;
        node->next = start->next;
        start->next->prev = node;
        start->next = node;
        node->prev = start;
    }

    void PushBack(T data)
    {
        ListNode<T>* node = new ListNode<T>();
        _ASSERT(node);
        node->data = data;
        node->prev = end->prev;
        end->prev->next = node;
        end->prev = node;
        node->next = end;
    }

    void Insert(ListNode<T>* node)
    {
        ListNode<T>* firstNode = node;
        ListNode<T>* lastNode = node->next;
        ListNode<T>* newNode = new ListNode<T>*;
        //ListNode<T>* newNode = new ListNode<T>;
        _ASSERT(newNode);

        firstNode = newNode->prev;
        lastNode = newNode->next;

        //delete node;
    }

    ListNode<T>* Begin()
    {
        return start->next;
    }

    ListNode<T>* End()
    {
        return end;
    }

    ListNode<T>* First()
    {
        _ASSERT(start->next != end);
        return start->next->data;
    }

    ListNode<T>* Last()
    {
        _ASSERT(end->prev != start);
            return end->prev->data;
    }

    int Count()
    {
        int m_count = 0;

        ListNode<T>* current = start->next;

        while (current != end)
        {
            ++current;
            ++m_count;
        }

        return m_count;
    }

    ListNode<T>* Delete(ListNode<T>* node)
    {
        ListNode<T>* prevNode = node->prev;
        ListNode<T>* nextNode = node->next;

        prevNode->next = nextNode;
        nextNode->prev = prevNode;

        delete node;

        return nextNode;
    }

    void Erase(Iter<T> & target)
    {
        target.current = Delete(target.current);
    }

    void Remove(T value)
    {
        ListNode<T>* current = start->next;

        while (current != end)
        {
            if (current.data == value)
            {
                current = Delete(current);
            }

            else
            {
            ++current;
            }
        }
    }

    void PopBack()
    {
        _ASSERT(end->prev != start);
        Delete(end->prev);
    }

    void PopFront()
    {
        _ASSERT(start->next != end);
        Delete(start->next);
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        ListNode<T>* current = start->next;

        while (current != end)
        {
            current = Delete(current);
            ++current;
        }
    }

private:
    ListNode<T>* start;
    ListNode<T>* end;
    int m_Iterator;
};
```

**ListNode.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "ListNode.h"

template <typename T>
class ListNode
{
public:
    ListNode() {};
    ~ListNode() {};

    T data;
    ListNode* next;
    ListNode* prev;
};
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Off topic: ListNode.h including itself seems an odd choice. Why do you need to do this?

Comment: First() seems to return the data not the node. Also you should not allocate space for a new newNodeCatch right before setting it to a new value.

Comment: A common recommendation when working with linked lists (and other pointer-driven data structures) is to draw pictures. Draw the list. As you make changes to the list, redraw the list . Visualize the changes. Show the connections between the nodes. If you cannot draw the list by following the the instruction s in your code, you have a bug in the code, and the difference between the expected and produced drawings will tell you where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue looks like it is here (it would be helpful to have the line number the error reported)

```
ListNode<T>* First()
    {
        _ASSERT(start->next != end);
        return start->next->data;
    }
```

The function is defined as return a pointer to a list node, however you are returning data, which is (in this case) an int, so the compiler is reporting exactly that:  *Error C2440 'return': cannot convert from 'int' to 'ListNode *'*

The function should return the first node so should be: start->next

Comment: `return start->next;`

Comment: In this case, yes. But OP's having `start` and `end` always pointing to dummy nodes is going to cause a whole lot of extra grief later.

Comment: I've applied the above change but now it is telling me the operands don't match. I have figured out that I can remove the * at the end of 
"ListNode<T>* newNode = new ListNode<T>*;" and it builds and works returning the first node's data as int!

before removing the extra * http://puu.sh/wsLy7/0db5cea645.png